# Get all dates with a week interval given a start date and end date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime

I have an event record database, I need to find all events for each costumer and group them in one week interval from the last record of each costumer until the first.

```
FirstEvent                  LastEvent               Client
==
2011-01-01 06:55:21.000 |2011-04-30 21:46:09.000    |Client1
2011-01-01 06:20:00.000 |2011-02-23 12:43:55.000    |Client2
2011-01-03 08:34:33.000 |2011-04-30 09:00:39.000    |Client3
2011-01-01 02:14:45.000 |2011-04-30 15:31:41.000    |Client4
2011-01-01 08:08:12.000 |2011-02-21 09:41:28.000    |Client5
2011-02-01 11:29:28.000 |2011-04-29 09:13:25.000    |Client6
```

Now I have to count the records of each client and group them like this

```
Client     From                    To                        Records
==
Client1   |2011-04-30 21:46:09.000 |2011-04-23 21:46:09.000  |200
Client1   |2011-04-16 21:46:09.000 |2011-04-09 21:46:09.000  |400
                                 ...Until the the first date
Client1   |2011-01-08 06:55:21.000 |2011-01-01 06:55:21.000  |250
Client2   |2011-02-23 12:43:55.000 |2011-02-16 12:43:55.000  |50
                                 ...The same for each user
```

I hope someone can help me find a way to output this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think this does exactly what you wish for:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2011-01-01 06:55:21.000', 120) AS event, 'client1' AS Client
INTO #EVENTS
UNION ALL SELECT '2011-01-08 06:55:20.000', 'client1'
UNION ALL SELECT '2011-04-30 21:46:09.000', 'client1'


;WITH E AS (
    SELECT
        Client,
        MIN(event) AS FirstEvent
    FROM #EVENTS
    GROUP BY Client
)
,B AS (
    SELECT
        E.Client,
        E.FirstEvent,
        COUNT(*) AS Records,
        DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, c.event - E.FirstEvent) / 7 AS [weeks]     
    FROM #EVENTS c
    JOIN E ON E.Client = c.Client
    GROUP BY E.Client, E.FirstEvent, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, c.event - E.FirstEvent) / 7
)
SELECT
    Client,
    DATEADD(WEEK, weeks, FirstEvent) AS [From],
    DATEADD(WEEK, weeks + 1, FirstEvent) AS [To],
    Records
FROM B
ORDER BY Client, weeks;

DROP TABLE #EVENTS
```

Though, if there are no records a certain week, it will leave out that row instead of returning a row containing the Records value of 0:

**Edit:**

If you wonder why I use `DAY` instead of `WEEK` for my `DATEDIFF`, it is to avoid problems whether Sunday or Monday is the first day of the week.

Comment: I'm adapting to my scenario and testing now. Ty

Comment: I removed it since it isn't really necessary. The output doesn't contain LastEvent, and only FirstEvent is needed as the week "origo". But the entire code piece is a running example, so you can just copy it and try it.

Comment: Ok, i got it. And i liked the day approach. It's working really fine with my data. if you don't mind, could you point me what i need to change so i can get the reverse? Starting from the last event, until the first.

Comment: @DaniloSouza: Of course. To get the reverse, you change `MIN` to `MAX`, and then you might want to change the DATEADD-lines that calculate the weeks. `DATEADD(WEEK, weeks - 1, FirstEvent) AS [From],     DATEADD(WEEK, weeks, FirstEvent) AS [To]`

Comment: @DaniloSouza: Changing `FirstEvent` to `LastEvent` might help to make it less confusing as well ;)

Comment: Thanks for the great help it's running perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can group by week using the DATEDIFF function.

```
SELECT e.[Client]
, [From] = MIN(e.EventDate)
, [To] = MAX(e.EventDate)
, [Records] = COUNT(*)
FROM Events AS e
GROUP BY e.[Client]
, DATEDIFF(week, '1900-01-01', e.EventDate)
```

Comment: I think Danilo wish to group weeks starting with the FirstEvent as some kind of origo and not actual weeks (1900-01-01). But otherwise a clean and simple answer.

Comment: You should add `e.[Client]` column to `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: ANisus, that's exactly it. But Anthony's answer gave me a really good picture on what i can do with the datediff.

Comment: ANisus made a great point in his answer. Use `DATEDIFF WEEK` with caution. The first day of the week is locale dependent. The week starts on Sunday in Asia & the Americas, and on Monday in European countries. To work around this use `DATEDIFF DAY` divided by 7 instead.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if the number of weeks between the start and end is less than 2048, if not then I would suggest using a numbers table.

```
SELECT
client
,DATEADD(WK,(number * -1) -1,fromdate) as [from]
,DATEADD(WK,number * -1,fromdate) as [to]
,COUNT(client) as records
from #sample
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT number FROM dbo.spt_values WHERE type = 'p') nums 
on nums.number <= DATEDIFF(WK,todate,fromdate)
GROUP BY client
,DATEADD(WK,(number * -1) -1,fromdate) 
,DATEADD(WK,number * -1,fromdate) 
ORDER BY 
client
,DATEADD(WK,(number * -1) -1,fromdate) DESC
```